# How to subclassing customcell in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've created a customcell which is inherited from UITableViewCell and added two labels(l1,l2) in IBOutlet.
Now again I've created another customCell which is inherited from Above CustomCell.

And I have registered these two custom cell using nibs(Xib) to Tableview.
When I try to access l1,l2 with respect of second custom cell app is crashing and saying **"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"**

Please help me on this.How can we subclass a customcell?

Comment: share that code.

Comment: Have you connected these `l1` and `l2` to the `UILabel` in your second cell nib?

Comment: I didn't connected.l1,l2 are already connected in 1st customcell,DO i need to connect them in scecondCell also?How can we connect them, as we wont get them in scecondCell nib

Comment: Yes I got it.I have drag&drop two lables on cell xib and connected them.Thank you Adil Soomro

Comment: @SandeepkumarRachha for you to access `l1` and `l2` in second xib you have to connect `IBoutlets` to second xib too. Since you have connected `l1` and `l2` in first xib does not mean that it is available in second xib too.